# Walk in / on /over: Which is the right preposition in the following scenario?

Tags: prepositions

I had to walk   IN / ON / OVER   frozen ruts in the snow.

In  my opinion it should be ON as I had to walk on a surface. However I came across 2 instances on the web where either it is IN or OVER.  May I know which is right and why is it so?

Comment: They're all much of a muchness - none of the above suggestions appear in Google Books as *walk XXX frozen ruts*, but they're all "acceptable", and would be understood to mean the same thing. On the other hand, I did come across [*I had to walk **across** the frozen ruts three times before he would believe that what looked like mud really wasn't*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22walk+across+the+frozen+ruts%22) - which seems at least as good, if not better.

Comment: @FumbleFingers:  in macmillandictionary I see the above sentence as I mentioned.

Comment: As I said, they're all acceptable. This isn't a matter of "right" or "wrong". Also note that since there isn't a specific term distinguishing the *raised* portions of such a frozen track from the *indented* ones to either side, in practice, ***ruts*** would be taken to refer to either/both in your context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To me, "walk over frozen ruts" does not have the same meaning as the other two and while in/on would have similar meaning I think that for most situations I would prefer one over the other.

Comment: @Sam: The way I see it, if you're *walking*, and the path consists of frozen ruts, *semantically* it makes no difference what preposition you use. It's not like there are multiple different ways you *could* move over such a surface, each made explicit by your choice of preposition. Stylistically, I could get behind ***through*** though, since it would metaphorically imply the "impediment to progress".

Answer (score 5):

Definition of rut is:

> a deep narrow mark in the ground made by a wheel

So, if you walk inside the rut, then you use `in`, like `I had to walk in frozen ruts in the snow.`

If you jump over a rut, then you use `over`.

For using `on`, it should generally be a raised surface, like a `bridge`.

Comment: One might also "walk *on* a bridge *over* the water"